# Using an enum and a switch statement c#

Tags: c#, enums, switch-statement

I am using an enum as my options for a switch statement and it works.  The problem is if the user enter a non valid option the program crashes.  What should I add so that the default is used?

my enum class

```
    public enum Options : byte
    {
        Display = 1,
        Add,
        Toggle,
        Max,
        Mean,
        Medium,
        Exit
    }
```

in main my switch statement

```
    string volString = Console.ReadLine();
    Options options = (Options)Enum.Parse(typeof(Options), volString);
    // this is the line that is giving me the runtime error. Since other options are not found
```

in the enum the program crashes.

```
                switch (options)
                {
                    case Options.Display: //dispaly regular time

                    case Options.Toggle://toggle 

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("entry blah blah");
                        break;
```

Comment: What kind of runtime error do you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
Options value;
if(!Enum.TryParse(volString, out value)) // note implicit <Options>
    value = Options.SomeDefaultValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, working with enums is new for me.  I wonder why enum parse is an option, tryparse makes more sense.

Comment: @Aaron firstly, the "out T" wasn't possible without generics, so wasn't possible until .net 2; secondly, a Parse is perfectly correct if you want to assert that the string **should be** a valid enum.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of `Enum.Parse` use `Enum.TryParse`... this will return a boolean to say if the text can be converted into your enum.  If it's true run your switch otherwise inform the user that they entered an invalid string.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) instead:

```
Options options;

if(!Enum.TryParse(volString, out options)) {
    // It wasn't valid input.
}
```

Comment: I still don't think it's accurate.

Comment: @Steve: Oops, thanks for pointing that out. (Yes, I'm a VB.NET person.)

Answer (score 0):

Look at Enum.TryParse(...) you can use this to check for invalid strings.